# Angular properties (variables) use in the view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of schools and a list of teachers.

Schools

```
    [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "nameOfInstitution": "Summer Elementary",
    "schoolLevel": "01304"
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "nameOfInstitution": "Grady Middle",
    "schoolLevel": "02400"
    }
    ]
```

Teachers

```
[
{
  "id": "1",
  "school": "1",
  "name": {
    "lastOrSurname": "HARRISON",
    "firstName": "JOHN",
    "middleName": ""
  }
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "school": "1",
  "name": {
    "lastOrSurname": "Nelson",
    "firstName": "Darren",
    "middleName": ""
  }
},
{
  "id": "3",
  "school": "2",
  "name": {
    "lastOrSurname": "Stewart",
    "firstName": "Manuel",
    "middleName": ""
  }
}]
```

In the controller I have 
...

```
$scope.schools = schools;
$scope.teachers = teachers;
```

The question is related to the view. How can I achieve this?

- Summer Elementary

  - JOHN HARRISON
  - Darren Nelson
- Grady Middle

  - Manuel Steward

I've been using the "ng-repeat" directive, but how can I display only the teachers that belong to each schools?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the teachers in your ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="school in schools">
  <div ng-repeat="teacher in teachers | filter: {school: school.id}">
```

But be sure to add an `id` property for each school that are used by the teachers.

Or if the `teacher.school` properties are the schools index in the schools array, you can do that:

```
<div ng-repeat="school in schools">
  <div ng-repeat="teacher in teachers | filter: {school: $index}">
```

A final note: this will work but if you have many schools and teacher, it would be more performant to perform the filtering from javascript before you display it, i.e. build a structure like

```
schools = [{
  nameOfInstitution: ...,
  schoolLevel: ...,
  teachers: [{
    lastOrSurname: ...
  }]
  // ... etc
}];
```

Comment: @PetrAveryanov why is it wrong? Indeed to work one need to add an `id` to every school. When the schools ids are their index I have put another example.

Comment: Yes, sorry! I meant to show the id in the schools json. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Thanks for the precision @ChrisF., so my answer is correct.

Comment: You always need exact filter for ids

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I still don't understand you, but assure you that it is the correct way to do it. I am matching the current `school.id` from outer repeater with the `teacher.school` from the inner one.

Comment: In the starting example ids were strings, and i.e. {id:"11"} matches filter:{id:"1"}

Comment: I think you are confused by how angular filters work. The expression being parsed, all strings will be converted to numbers, see proof here: http://jsfiddle.net/jr173ph2/

Answer (score 0):

Use filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="school in schools">
  {{school.nameOfInstitution}}
<p ng-repeat="teacher in teachers | filter:{school: ''+ ($index+1)}:true">
  {{teacher.name.lastOrSurname}}
</p>
</div>
```

But you'd better have some sort of id for schools...